# How to add JVM argument `-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false` to IBM MQ?

Tags: java, encryption, ibm-mq, ibm-jre

Recently I've been migrated to IBM MQ v8 to IBM MQ v9 (v9.1.2.0 specifically). I used SSL to communicate with the broker. So as per [Deprecated CipherSpecs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q014265_.htm) document, IBM has deprecated number of cipher suites that came up with MQ 8 and seems all of the cipher suites I've been using, have been deprecated with v9 upward. Therefore, I've implemented new TLS cipher suites to work with my application which runs on a Oracle JVM (version 1.8.0_211). Ever since I'm getting following exception in the application though;

```
com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2400'.
    at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.constructMQCD(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:1437)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.constructCNO(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:1537)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:221)
    ... (Omitted the rest)
```

When I dig about the reason, found that's a problem with IBM MQ cipher suites and Oracle JRE cipher suite name mismatch. But I did refer [TLS CipherSpecs and CipherSuites in IBM MQ classes for JMS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q113220_.htm) document to map cipher suite names. I used some of **Equivalent CipherSuite (Oracle JRE)** column values in my application that already available in IBM MQ as well. But still getting the issue.

After I found [this answer](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/493951/unable-to-connect-to-queue-manager-mqv90-from-jms/?smartspace=powerai) that advises to add this `-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false` argument to IBM MQ's JRE (As I understand). This might allow IBM MQ to use Oracle complied cipher suite names. My question is,

1. How to add this JVM argument `-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false` to IBM MQ JRE?

This [Problem Connecting a Java Client (JMS) to a IBM MQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52775733/problem-connecting-a-java-client-jms-to-a-ibm-mq) question suggests that the same parameter needed to be added to the application as a system property `System.setProperty("com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings", "false")`, but it didn't make any different.

[Java connection to WMQ 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43194227/java-connection-to-wmq-8) question also states the same solution, but doesn't mention how to add this JVM argument to IBM MQ.

**Update 1**

I did some research about how to add a JVM argument to IBM MQ. But I was only able to find a solutions for Websphere application server.

CipherSuite I'm currently using in the application is;

> **TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256** (Oracle JRE complied)

IBM MQ has respective;

> **ECDHE_ECDSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA256** (IBM MQ complied)

**Update 2**

After creating a `key.kdb` file with `ikeyman` tool with the `stash` option queue manager can successfully read the certificates in it. Also, I've included a self-signed certificate labeled with `ibmwebspheremq<lowercase_queue_manage_name>`. But now I'm getting a different exception in the client side;

```
Exception in thread "main" com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2059'.
    at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:255)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11._createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:450)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:487)
    at com.ibm.mq.StoredManagedConnection.<init>(StoredManagedConnection.java:97)
```

and in the MQ log I can find this entry;

```
AMQ9637E: Channel is lacking a certificate.
```

with some explanation.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194143/discussion-on-question-by-sachith-dickwella-how-to-add-jvm-argument-dcom-ibm-m).

Comment: I've made `SSLCAUTH(OPTIONAL)` and then as `userId` and `password`, I passed my Windows credentials. Then MQ gives this error `AMQ5542I: The failed authentication check was caused by the queue manager
CONNAUTH CHCKCLNT(REQDADM) configuration`. How can I resolve this issue? I don't have any `MQCSP Block` record as well. I've created `Channel Authentication Record` to allow access for my user, but still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working for while, I was able resolve this issue. Since the beginning I had this certificate configuration issue in the application side. Even after creating `self-signed` certificate labeled after `ibmwebspheremq<queue_manager_name>` and shared the extracted certificates with the client application using `ikeyman` tool, `AMQ9637E: Channel is lacking a certificate.` occurred.

In a nutshell, to resolve this issue entirely, I did the following;

Update the client MQ dependency to `com.ibm.mq.allclient:v9.1.2.0`. If you're using maven, use following dependency ([MQC91: IBM MQ Clients](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24044791)).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
    <version>9.1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Now, if the application runs on an Oracle JVM, we should convince the MQ client lib to use Oracle JVM complied cipher suite names. To do that, either add this `-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false` as a JVM flag or add this `System.setProperty("com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings", "false")` as a system property.

Select a appropriate cipher suite to communicate with the MQ. This [TLS CipherSpecs and CipherSuites in IBM MQ classes for JMS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q113220_.htm) document would be helpful as IBM has [deprecated](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q014265_.htm) number of **weak** cipher specs IBMMQ 9 onwards.

I would suggest to use `ECDHE_*` cipher specs as they provide [Ephemeral Keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_key) to maintain [Forward Secrecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy).

Then, using `ikeyman` GUI tool,  I created a `self-signed` certificate labeled after `ibmwebspheremq<queue_manager_name>` name and instead of extracting the `.arm` file, I export the certificate as `.jks` files. Both `keystore.jks` and `truststore.jks` files exported from the same certificate. After, attached them to the application using system properties;

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "truststore.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "<password>");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "keystore.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "<password>");
```

With this configuration, SSL handshake issue went away, but the IBM MQ was still asking for user authentication with a user name and password. In order to provide them, should add these properties to `MQEnvironment`,

```
MQEnvironment.properties.put(com.ibm.mq.constants.CMQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, "<user_name>");
MQEnvironment.properties.put(com.ibm.mq.constants.CMQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "<password>");
```

These credentials were system credentials in my case.

If you simply want to skip user authentication like this, you can update IBMMQ config to skip credential check using `runmqsc` CLI tool like this (Refer this [Turning on connection authentication on a queue manager](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q113250_.htm) document),

```
ALTER QMGR CONNAUTH(USE.PW)
DEFINE AUTHINFO(USE.PW) +
AUTHTYPE(IDPWOS) +
FAILDLAY(10) +
CHCKLOCL(OPTIONAL) +
CHCKCLNT(OPTIONAL)
REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(CONNAUTH)
```

Note that `CHCKCLNT` value needed to set as `OPTIONAL` to ignore client user credential check. IBM MQ should start to work with the client application whilst SSL enabled after these configurations.

Kudos to @JoshMc for the support to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Adding answer to capture information provided to OP in comments that have been removed.

---

See the following IBM MQ Knowledge center page for a table showing cert type compatibility with MQ v9.1:

[IBM MQ 9.1.x/IBM MQ/Securing/Confidentiality of messages/Enabling CipherSpecs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q014260_.htm)

The ciphers with `ECDHE_ECDSA` require a suite b cert for the queue manager. If using a client cert for your application it will also need to be suite b.

Note that you can use `ECDHE_RSA` ciphers with non-suite b certs.

---

The stash file (`key.sth for example`) is used by the queue manager to access the `kdb` file. The java equivalent on the client end is you specifying the jks password.